# High Efficient MDB using spring jms or ntegration

Tags: spring, optimization, jms, spring-integration

I have requirement where  I need receive message from MQ every seconds , the message will be in XML format , so i need to write a high effecient MDB. Problem here is I am new to MQ,JMS,Spring JMS and Spring Integration but not spring tough.

Based on google search so far I am able to write below code

MDB

```
import javax.jms.Message;  
import javax.jms.MessageListener;  
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

public class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener{  
    @Override  
    public void onMessage(Message m) {  
        TextMessage message=(TextMessage)m;  
        try{  
            System.out.println(message.getText());  
        }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();  }  
    }  
}
```

XMl config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"  

    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd">  

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"  
 p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />  

<bean id="listener" class="com.springexample.MyMessageListener"></bean>  

<jms:listener-container container-type="default" connection-factory="connectionFactory"  
 acknowledge="auto">  
<jms:listener destination="myfirstqueue" ref="listener" method="onMessage"></jms:listener>  
</jms:listener-container>  

</beans>
```

I know what i have written is very basic one but i dont know what is the efficient one , how to provide transaction support and how to handle such load where i am going to recieve message every seconds.

Should i use Spring JMS or Spring Integration any help is much appreciated.

Comment: a "xml message every seconds" is not really a high requirement. any mq/configuration can handle that

Comment: can you please let me what kind of configuration can help

Comment: agreed, a highly-scaleable solution is one where you might be processing 1000s of messages per second, one message every few seconds shouldn't be a problem unless you can't process a message in that time frame.  At that point, I'd be trying to optimize my application logic and speed things up that way.

Answer (score 0):

The question you asked is which to use: definitely go Spring JMS